# When/where to set network bond (active-backup) interface priorities on boot?

Tags: linux, backup, priority

This is a follow-up to [linux bonding active-backup mode set priority for multiple interfaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/761819/linux-bonding-active-backup-mode-set-priority-for-multiple-interfaces) I'm too new to post a comment there.

I've confirmed that `ip link set dev <x> type bond_slave prio <y>` works as expected. How can I execute these commands at the appropriate time on boot? There is no underlying configuration for **prio**. It can only be set after the interface is *enslaved*.

For those who have never used this feature, it looks like this:

config

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
    # gateway 172.16.0.1
    address 172.16.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    bond-slaves eno8 eno7 eno6 eno5 
    bond-mode active-backup
    bond-miimon 1000
    bond-downdelay 3000
    bond-updelay 3000
```

boot

```
bond0: (slave eno8): Enslaving as a backup interface with a down link
bond0: (slave eno7): Enslaving as a backup interface with a down link
bond0: (slave eno6): Enslaving as a backup interface with a down link
bond0: (slave eno5): Enslaving as a backup interface with a down link
bond0: (slave eno7): link status up, enabling it in 0 ms
bond0: (slave eno7): link status definitely up, 10000 Mbps full duplex
bond0: (slave eno7): making interface the new active one
bond0: active interface up!
```

I'm using this for auto-configuration rather than redundancy. That's why my time parameters are so large. The change doesn't need to happen instantly. I can't use a simple **primary**, because I want to give preference to *both* eno7 and eno8 which are 10GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `config` snippet looks like classic Debian-style `/etc/network/interfaces`. You might find this in distributions related to Debia, like Ubuntu, Mint, Kali and others. Distributions that are not related to Debian can have a completely different network configuration file syntax. This is one of the reasons why you should always specify the *name and version of the distribution you're using* when posting a Linux question.

If my guess is correct and this is for Debian or related distribution, use the `up` keyword and the `ip` command:

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
    # gateway 172.16.0.1
    address 172.16.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    bond-slaves eno8 eno7 eno6 eno5 
    bond-mode active-backup
    bond-miimon 1000
    bond-downdelay 3000
    bond-updelay 3000
    up /usr/bin/ip link set dev eno7 type bond_slave prio <y>
    up /usr/bin/ip link set dev eno8 type bond_slave prio <y> # repeat as necessary
```

Comment: Yes, my first attempt is on a Debian system (Proxmox host). Your suggestion works as requested. rc.local also works, but the activity occurs later after the bond has already selected an interface (without priority).

Where can I find the documentation for up/down & the pre-/post- variants used in  the interface file? The ip commands execute one time, immediately following the final bond 'enslaving'-- even if no interface is UP.

ip -d link show dev bond0

displays DOWN. This seems like a contradiction. The interface file must have a different meaning/context for 'up'?

Comment: You'll find the documentation using the command `man interfaces`; see the chapter titled `IFACE OPTIONS`. Interfaces have two distinct up/down states: an *administrative* state and an *operational* state. If an interface is configured but there is no link, it will be administratively up but operationally down - or in other words, it's been configured to *want* to be up, but it *cannot* do that until a link is established. The `up` commands will be executed after the interface is configured administratively up; the bond's operational state will depend on if any slaves have a link or not.